# ToUniversalTime() - too slow?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, utc

I save a big set of data where each record has a time-mark. I wanna save each item also with UTC time-mark so I convert the original time with use of ToUniversalTime() (VB.NET). The use of this method appears to be quite slow. Do you have any tips how to accelerate the process?

```
For Each i In CollectionOutput.Select(Function(f) f)
    Dim utcTimeMark = i.GetTIMEMARK.ToUniversalTime()
    contextEmanagement.pr_Collection_Store(i.GetID, i.GetTIMEMARK, utcTimeMark, i.GetVALUE)
Next
```

Where .pr_Collection_Store calls SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: Is every value in the database shifted by the same number of minutes (e.g. all source data is from the same time zone, and all data in the set is either not affected at all by daylight saving time, or affected by the same amount?

Comment: ToUniversalTime is not "slow". Your database access is taking most of the time.

Comment: That's where I'm not sure whether DB access or ToUniversalTime() method. I did not measured it.

Comment: Calling a stored procedure in a loop from code is never going to be fast.  Just let the db handle the time stamp you need when the record is inserted or modified.

Comment: Or is there any tip, how to speed up the process?

Comment: Pass the set of `i` values to a single stored procedure, once, that converts all of the values and then sends them back. You can use a table-valued parameter if you are on SQL Server 2008 or better, or various string splitting techniques if on 2000/2005.

Comment: ToUniversalTime() is easier to implement (on the app layer). I haven't find any similar elegant function in SQL Server (TSQL).

Comment: This is why I asked whether all the input values could be relied upon to adjust to what `ToUniversalTime()` returns right now. In SQL Server can't you do `DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @input)`? Anyway the real problem is that you should be able to deal with these values as a set instead of one at a time. You could continue to use `ToUniversalTime()` but store the values in, say, a `DataTable` and pass them to a single stored procedure, once.

Comment: Thank you for the tip for table-valued parameter and the advise to the procedure calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your stored procedure presumably does something like this (I am absolutely guessing at data types here, and I'm assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or better - please specify your version when asking questions!):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pr_Collection_Store
  @GetID INT,
  @GetTimeMark DATETIME, 
  @UTCTimeMark DATETIME,
  @GetValue INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.SomeTable(ID, TimeMark, UTCTimeMark, Value)
    SELECT @GetID, @GetTimeMark, @UTCTimeMark, @GetValue;
END
GO
```

You could do this instead:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Collection AS TABLE
(
  GetID       INT,
  GetTimeMark DATETIME,
  UTCTimeMark DATETIME,
  GetValue    INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pr_Collection_Store2
  @Collection AS dbo.Collection READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.SomeTable(ID, TimeMark, UTCTimeMark, Value)
    SELECT GetID, GetTimeMark, UTCTimeMark, GetValue
    FROM @Collection AS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeTable WHERE ID = c.GetID);
END
GO
```

Then from the app. Sorry, I know C#, hopefully you can translate this to VB.NET.

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("i"));
foreach(var i in CollectionOutput)
{ 
    tvp.Rows.Add(i.GetID, i.GetTIMEMARK, i.GetTIMEMARK.ToUniversalTime(), i.GetValue); 
}

using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.pr_Collection_Store2", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Collection", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Btw: I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What I have found so far, that I cannot use table-valued parameters in stored procedure with use of Entity Framework. So I can reach the target only with use of an "old" approach - as you suggest here.

Comment: If you can pass a single string (e.g. comma-separated values) you could look at the approaches here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup.aspx

Comment: is there any elegant way, how to store values in TABLE type - but control the duplicates on insert (not given by ID)?

Comment: TVPs are read only, so you either remove the duplicates before going in, or use GROUP BY or DISTINCT when querying.

Comment: I'll explain deeper: the source rows (that could be stored into TVP) are all unique (it's a feed from Serial Port). But on the insert it has to be checked, whether a row from the source table is not already contained in the target DB-table.

Comment: Ok, added a where clause that makes sure that only new rows or added. But is there any interest in updating the rows that are already there? E.g. ID = 5 might already exist, but is it possible that GetTIMEMARK or GetValue have changed?